# positioning a div below a fixed div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've been asking Chat GPT about this and it tells me that the Content div should be placed below the Header div, which is what I want.

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
```

But both locally and in several online HTML editors, the Content div is placed on top of the Header div.

Is Chat GPT stupid, or am I stupid (probably)?

Comment: With the smidgen of code you posted, what are you expecting to happen? As it stands, yes, they'd overlap, as positioning something as fixed removes it from the flow of the document, allowing in your case, the content div to move up the page

Comment: the content **is** behind the header but visually you cannot see this if you keep both of them with the same color

Comment: @j08691 as I wrote - I want the content div to be placed below the header div.

Comment: "*Is Chat GPT stupid*". It has literally no intelligence. It's a regurgitation machine (with a very polished English language frontend).

Answer (score 0):

Its just behind your header. See the changes.

```css
.header {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div>Header</div>
</div>

<div class="content">Content</div>
```

Comment: Well, according to Chat GPT I don't need to use any margin-top on the .content...

Comment: @user3764769 You may be thinking of the vertical, y axis, while ChatGPT may be referring to the z axis (depth). The word 'below' can be used for either and not be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Positioning a DiV below a fixed Div is done by making its position ***absolute***.
I hope you got the answer by now.

```css
.header {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
}

.content {
  top: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Header</div>

<div class="content">Content</div>
```